# Retain styling when downloading .html file (React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, download

Here is a simplified version of my React component:

```
export class SomePage extends Component {

  downloadAsHTML() {
    const element = document.createElement("a");

    const file = new Blob([document.getElementById('second-child-div').outerHTML], {
      type: "text/html"
    });

    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "file.html";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="first-child-div">Stuff here</div>
        <div id="second-child-div" onClick={()=>this.downloadAsHTML()}>
           <span className="some-other-styling-here">
              <h1> Title </h1>
              <p> Paragraph </p>
              More things here
           </span>
           More html elements, nested styling, and text here
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

When the user clicks on `second-child-div` and the `div` gets downloaded as an `.html` file, I want the downloaded `.html` file to retain the styling of all the `classNames` and `html` selectors (like `#second-child-div h1` that would be in .css). What is the best way to do this?

One way I considered was creating another file called `Styles.js`:

```
const Styles = {
  container: {
    'padding': '30px',
    'border'
  },
  anotherContainer:  {
    'color': 'blue',
    'background': 'yellow'
  }
  containerH1: {
    'font-size': '20px'
  }
  containerParagraph: {
    'font-size': '20px'
  },
}

export default Styles;
```

and then import it as such:

```
import "Styles" from "./Styles.js"

//in second-child-div:

<div id="second-child-div" style={Styles.container} onClick={()=>this.downloadAsHTML()}>
   <span style={Styles.anotherContainer}>
      <h1 style={Styles.containerH1}> Title </h1>
      <p style={Styles.containerParagraph}> Paragraph </p>
       More things here
   </span>
   More html elements, nested styling, and text here
</div>
```

In my actual app, I have dozens and dozens of styling, with css selectors and such. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can probably copy all css files into the html style tag

Comment: Note that you're not asking about the styling for `second-child-div`, but for it, _and all of its descendants_. Not even the dev tools are that elaborate, showing only the applicable styling per single selected element, so you're almost certainly looking at walking the DOM tree for that node, and saving (a subset of) the computed style for each element (subset mostly because you almost certainly don't want to save all the properties that use their defaults) with an appropriate selector. I.e. manually building a completely new style sheet for just that element and its descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the CSS loaded into the page at the time the button is clicked, then inline the CSS into that HTML file inside of `<style>` tags before it is saved out.

This approach is pretty brute force. I don't try to find which styles apply to the element you are exporting, it just gets all of them.

```
const downloadAsHTML = () => {
  const element = document.createElement("a");

  const domNodeToSave = document.getElementById("second-child-div");
  const modifiedDomNodeToSave = domNodeToSave.cloneNode(true);
  modifiedDomNodeToSave.style.margin =
    "10px"; // example modificaiton

  const htmlSnippet = modifiedDomNodeToSave.outerHTML;

  const styleSheets = document.styleSheets;

  let allStyles = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    const styleSheet = styleSheets[i];

    const rules = styleSheet.cssRules;

    for (let j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
      const rule = rules[j];

      allStyles += rule.cssText + "\n";
    }
  }

  const styleBlock = `<style>${allStyles}</style>`;
  htmlSnippet += styleBlock;

  const file = new Blob([htmlSnippet], {
    type: "text/html",
  });

  element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  element.download = "file.html";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Where would `divHtml` be used?

Comment: Apologies this line can be deleted. I'm editing my post

Comment: No worries. Do you know if there's a way to apply a style just for the download and then remove the style? For example, adding a `margin` to `second-child-div` so it's included in the downloaded file but not have that show on the UI?

Comment: One way would be to copy the div in memory (this would mean its not actually displayed), add a inline `style=` attribute and then save that one. I could edit my answer with this if you like?

Comment: Ive edited with an example. The margin I applied is arbitrary but you can do whatever with that cloned node without affecting the one in the page itself.

Comment: I keep getting this error: `modifiedDomNodeToSave.querySelector(...) is null`. Here's a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ishizaka-9zd80m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that you don't need to call `querySelector` on `modifiedDomNodeToSave` and can directly apply the style like this: `modifiedDomNodeToSave.style.color`

Comment: Oops yeh. The reason for that is `querySelector` looks at the children of the element it is called on, but the element you want to modify *is* that element you want in your case. What you have works fine. I've edited my post.

Comment: Hello @adsy, for this same issue, I have an `img` that is not showing in the .html downloaded file, although it works fine on the UI. Do you know what may be done here?

Comment: @penguin You could inline IMG image data by converting them to data URIs before outputting the HTML (embed them). You'd first select all IMG tags, get the src attribute, and pipe it all through something like https://github.com/WangYuLue/image-conversion (to data uri) then replace the src attribute with the result.